# jQuery if value bigger then val

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am not sure why this is not working, after all if I am correct it should be fine.

But when I run the following

```
if(lastchatid < obj.id)
```

it seems not to run.

basiclly lastchatid stores the last chat id and the obj.id is the new obj.id since the last chat id.

I am wondering why this would not work.

Comment: What do you mean `it seems to not run`? Do a `console.log(lastchatid)` and `console.log(obj.id)` and see what they output.

Comment: Need more information to answer this. Can you post up more source code?

Comment: Your descriptions of the variables just reiterate the names and give no meaning or definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lastchatid` and `obj.id` are number values you can try using:

```
lastchatid = parseInt(lastchatid, 10)
obj.id= parseInt(obj.id, 10)
```

and then

```
if(lastchatid < obj.id)
```

Comment: You mean `parseInt`, and you should also specify a radix (10) as the second parameter. Furthmore, the `<` is not tied to integers only; it works for strings, floating point, etc etc.

Comment: @matt yeah sure, but in many times in javascript, you must use parseInt, for example if you read value from hmtl, then you don't get int but string